# Can i change "xsdlib.jar" exception messages?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have one `.xsd` file, in this file including tag binding information like attribute id,type,name etc.

When I import the `.xml` file related to `.xsd` I get an exception

```
Location: line 1618 07:18:36,465 ERROR [STDERR]javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException:
  the length of the value is 11, but the required maximum is 10.
```

my tag is

```
 <xs:element name="name" type="String10"/>

 <xs:simpleType name="String10">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:normalizedString">
            <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>`
```

I don't want to change the size of my tag but I want to change the error message format, like `length of "size" is 11.` instead of `value`.

Comment: Why bother? Those messages are meant for the programmer only and you seem to understand what they mean.

Comment: because i want to add more details in this error message.It is possible ?

Comment: basically no, you can decompile that jar, change it's code and recompile it and then use your own version / fork the source code in case it's open, but changing exception messages is not an intended feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with UnmarshalException after catching it and you can throw a new UnmarshalException with your desired message